# Свернуть и развернуть текст по нажатию

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть текст, который сворачивается по нажатию иконки и разворачивается. Мне нужно, чтобы он на экранах компьютера был обычным, без иконки, а в `responsive` версии сворачивался и разворачивался. Есть идеи как это реализовать?

```css
img {
  height: 100%;
}

.read-more-trigger {
  height: 20px;
}

.read-more-state:checked~.read-more-trigger>img {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: transform 0.65s ease-in-out;
}

.read-more-trigger>img {
  transition: transform 0.65s ease-in-out;
}

.read-more-state {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state:checked~.read-more-wrap .read-more-target {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state~.read-more-trigger:before {
  content: '';
}

.read-more-state:checked~.read-more-trigger:before {
  content: '';
}

.read-more-state:checked~.read-more-trigger:before {
  background: url(arrow%20up%20grad.svg);
}

.read-more-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  color: #666;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 2;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: .25em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="post-1" />
  <p class="read-more-wrap">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    <span class="read-more-target">
  Libero fuga facilis vel consectetur quos sapiente deleniti eveniet dolores tempore eos deserunt officia quis ab? Excepturi vero tempore minus beatae voluptatem!
  </span>
  </p>
  <label for="post-1" class="read-more-trigger"><img src="arrow%20grad.svg"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну в чем проблема? Скрой иконку, когда с компа зашли на сайт...

Comment: @Air, это решение не проще, чем скрыть иконку ориентируясь по ширине окна.

Comment: @NikitaA.Slutsky, а я о чем по твоему говорил?

Comment: @Air, вы предложили определять тип устройства.

Comment: @NikitaA.Slutsky, ......))) пусть по твоему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь правилом `@media`.

```css
.read-more-state {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-button {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .read-more-target {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 0;
  }
  
  .read-more-button {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background: url(https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }

  .read-more-state:checked + .read-more-target {
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: inherit;
  }

  .read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-button {
    background: blue url(https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/yx/r/tjBuxcd0g0m.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
  
  <input id="read-more-state-1" class="read-more-state" type="checkbox">
  
  <span class="read-more-target">
    Libero fuga facilis vel consectetur quos sapiente deleniti eveniet dolores tempore 
    eos deserunt officia quis ab? Excepturi vero tempore minus beatae voluptatem!
  </span>
  
  <label for="read-more-state-1" class="read-more-button"></label>
</p>
```

- По просьбе автора вопроса изменил на картинки.
- Убрал `span.read-more-button-icon` за ненадобностью.

Comment: а если у  меня есть свои иконки(+ и - например). как на них можно заменить?

Comment: В имеете ввиду менять две иконки. Для этого вам надо задавать изображения с помощью css и менять с помощью правил `.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-button .read-more-button-icon` и `.read-more-state ~ .read-more-button .read-more-button-icon` (если смотреть по моей реализации).

Comment: отметил как верный. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте при помощи js:

```
if(document.documentElement.clientWidth < 1200){
        document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "none" 
else
        document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "block"
```

Comment: JS то тут на кой)))????